# PHP if doesn't work with multiple php opening and closing tags

Tags: php, if-statement

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here  that throws me a server error

```
<?php if(true){?>

<hr/>

<?php}?>
```

Comment: Should work but you could try like this
if(true):
endif;

Comment: keep downvoting ..but i thinks this is a question that will save tons of time for many other developers

Comment: @user1485518 Don't worry too much about downvotes, rep will come and go. Instead have a look at the answer I posted and test it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space after `<?php` like this:

```
<?php if(true){?>

<hr/>

<?php } ?>
```

PHP looks for an opening tag that contains *exactly* `<?php` and does not understand `<?php}`.

The code as above renders a horizontal rule as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
<?php if(true): ?>

<hr/>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can display only "< hr >" tags.

If condition is always true, no make sense to use if(true).

You can break php and show de hr tag, or use echo with hr.

Comment: I believe he was testing out code rather than posting an *exact* copy of what he is writing :)